# prove $x^{2n} + y^{2m} = 1$ is a "closed" shape

Tags: circles, graphing-functions

> How do I show that $x^{2n} + y^{2m} = 1$ has a domain of $|x| \leq 1$? How would I show the opposite, that 
>   $$x^{2n-1} + y^{2m-1} = 1$$ 
>   has a domain covering all real values?

Comment: Notice that one pair of exponents is both even, and the other pair is both odd.

Comment: You can parametrise it as a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)

Comment: If $x$ is bigger than one then $x^{2n}>1$ and you'd have $y^{2m}$ being negative.  But $y^{2m}=(y^m)^2$ which must be positive because it's a square.

Comment: Well, $x^{2n} + y^{2m} = (x^m)^2 + (y^m)^2 = 1$  If $w = x^n; v =y^m$ this is a circle with domain $-1 \le w,v \le 1$ which means $x^n, y^m$ must have a range within $[-1, 1]$  If m,n are integers to have such a range the domain must be $1 \le x,y \le 1$.